# Distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$, exponential

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

On this [site](https://ckrao.wordpress.com/2012/05/27/the-distribution-of-xxy-is-uniform-when-x-and-y-are-iid-exponential/) the distribution of $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ has been derived. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independently distributed exponential random variables with mean $1$. This means $f_X(x)=e^{-x}=P(X\geq x)$.

Then it starts with

For $t\in (0,1)$

$$P\left(\frac{X}{X+Y}\leq t\right)=P\left(\frac{X+Y}{X}\leq \frac1t\right)$$

$$=P(Y\geq X(\frac1t-1))$$

So far so good. But the next step I really don´t understand.

$$=\int_0^{\infty} f_X(x)\cdot P(Y\geq x(\frac1t-1)) \, dx$$

It is obvious that $X \in (0, \infty)$. But the rest is unclear to me. I hope somebody can explain me why the two latter lines are equal.

Thanks for your time

*calculus*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, this is simply an application/extension of the law of total probability for sets, i.e., $$P(A) = \sum_i P(B_i) \times P(A | B_i)$$ where $\{B_i\}$ is a disjoint of partition of the sample space.

If you thought about the joint pdf analogous to $P(A \, \text{and} \, B)$, marginal and conditional PDF's in the obviously analogous way, one can see that $$ \iint f(x,y) \, dx \, dy = \int f_X(x) \, f_{Y|X}(y|x) dx$$

Keep that in the background. Now dealing with $P(Y \geq X(1/t - 1))$ you are dealing with two random variables $X$ and $Y$ simultaneously. A way to approach it (from the total law of probability perspective) is to condition on one of them ($X$ in this case, which allows to handle that random variable $X$ as a real number $x$), multiply the expression by probability of $X$ being approximately that $x$ (this is loosely speaking the density of $X$), then integrate across all possible values of $x$. This is really an application of the law of total probability.

Comment: So you mean that $f_{Y|X}(y|x)=P(Y|Y\geq x(\frac{1}t -1))$ ?

Comment: well, to flush out the details, one has to be a bit more careful. The probability you are starting with is a double integral of the joint pdf over a specific region in $\mathcal{R}^2$. So some nuances get in the way. Hand waving over those (for the sake of clarity), I am saying $$P(Y \geq X \, c) = \int P(Y \geq X \, c \, | \, X) f_X(x) dx $$

Comment: ... Then in the probability inside the integrand on the right, the $X$ (a random variable) can be replaced with $x$ (a real number)

Comment: ...essentially (again with some hand waving) one is dealing with the 2-d integral by slicing across "each $x$ coordinate" (which is technically not kosher because $\mathcal{R}$ is not countable).

Comment: I think I get it. Thanks for your additional comments.

Answer (score 2):

This is (one way) how we compute the expectation of a function of a random variable.  We write

$$
E[g(X)] = \int_{x=0}^\infty f_X(x) g(x) \, dx
$$

where $f_X(x)$ is the PDF of $X$.  This is assuming that $X$ ranges from $0$ to $\infty$; adjust the limits of integration accordingly if it's otherwise.

Some intuition for this expression might be obtained by considering the discrete case.  Suppose a random variable $X$ takes on values $1$, $2$, and $3$ with probabilities $p_1 = 1/2, p_2 = 1/3, p_3 = 1/6$.  What is $E(X^2)$?  We would write

$$
E(X^2) = \sum_{k=1}^3 p_k k^2 = \frac{10}{3}
$$

and in general,

$$
E[g(X)] = \sum_{k=1}^3 p_k g(k)
$$

Well, the continuous case is much the same thing, except that instead of $p_k$, we have $f_X(x)\, dx$.  But otherwise, the principle is the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don´t understand in which way the expaction is involved here.

Comment: @BruceET I still don´t know from where the expectation comes. It is not mentioned on the site.

Comment: @BruceET My question is: How can we deal the expectation although in the second line or somewhere else the expactation (operator) is not mentioned in the article.